# Is it possible to fully hide the app bar in xfce?

Tags: xfce

When "Automatically show and hide the panel" is checked, there is still a small sliver of the app bar that shows. Is it possible to fully hide this in the xfce desktop? Google yields no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/.gtkrc-2.0` :

```
style "xfce-panel-window-style"
{
  # Size of autohide window in pixels
  XfcePanelWindow::autohide-size = 3
}
```

- http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/theming

(it was the first google hit to [xfce+fully+hide+panel](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=5829)  )

Comment: FYI all of the variables and the line at the end from the docs needs to be in there; otherwise, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, quit the panel process:

```
xfce4-panel -q
```

Ref:

> https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/theming