# Fully hide panel in xfce (gtk 3.0?)

Tags: xfce

Currently, when I set my panel to intelligently or always hide, it still uses up a few pixels at the edge of the screen that I would like to get rid of.

I found this [Is it possible to fully hide the app bar in xfce?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334698/is-it-possible-to-fully-hide-the-app-bar-in-xfce) post, but putting a .gtkrc-file in my HOME-directory does not work for me.
I am using debian stretch and I am not sure, if this uses gtk 2 or 3 (or a mixture?) , but I read here https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2011-March/msg00108.html that the set-up file does not work the same for gtk 3.

So, apparently I need to create a `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`. So my questions are:
what should be in this file? Where do I put it? XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not defined.

Comment: you can try to ask here : https://forum.xfce.org/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I errantly thought debian stretch xfce used gtk 3 but the old gtk 2 solution with a .gtkrc-2.0 still works. However, the width will always be at least 1 pixel. (That's why I thought it didn't work at first...)
The workaround some nice person in the xfce forum forum.xfce.org (thanks ctac_) suggested is to set the opacity of the panel to 0, which yields a surprisingly decent look.